# Prove that every vector in $U + V$ is of the form: $u + v$ with $u \in U$ and $v \in V$

Tags: linear-algebra

By definition, we have

$$ U + V := \text{span}(U \cup V) $$

**Note: Definition given in class.

First, we define $V$ and $U$:

$$ U = a_1 \cdot u_1 + \ldots + a_n \cdot u_n \text{ with } \forall i \in \mathbb{N}, u_i \in U \text{ and } a_i \in \mathbb{R}^n $$

$$ V = b_1 \cdot v_1 + \ldots + b_n \cdot v_n \text{ with } \forall i \in \mathbb{N}, v_i \in V \text{ and } b_i \in \mathbb{R}^n $$

That said, we have

$$ U + V := \text{span}(a_1 \cdot u_1 + \ldots + a_n \cdot u_n + b_1 \cdot v_1 + \ldots + b_n \cdot v_n) $$

How can I conclude this proof?

Comment: Your attempt is wrong. Answer me this: What does $x \in \text{span}(S)$ tells you?

Comment: Thank you! After your comment, I spoke to my teacher and he explained this concept to me again (and made the same comment as you)

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt doesn't seem correct to me.

**My attempt:**

By the definition given by the OP, if $x\in U+V$, then $x\in \operatorname{span}\left(U\cup V\right)$.

Let $U\setminus V=\{y_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda_1\}$, $U\cap V=\{z_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda_2\}$, and $V\setminus U=\{w_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda_3\}$, where $\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2,\Lambda_3$ are indexing sets.

Since $U\cup V=\left(U\setminus V\right)\cup \left(U\cap V\right)\cup\left( V\setminus U\right)$, if $x\in \operatorname{span}\left(U\cup V\right)$, then
$$x=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_1^\prime}a_\lambda y_\lambda+\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_2^\prime}b_\lambda z_\lambda+\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_3^\prime}c_\lambda w_\lambda,$$
for some $a_\lambda,b_\lambda,c_\lambda\in\Bbb R$ and $\Lambda_1^\prime,  \Lambda_2^\prime$, and $\Lambda_3^\prime$ are some finite subsets of $\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2$, and $\Lambda_3$, respectively.

Note that $\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_1^\prime}a_\lambda y_\lambda+\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_2^\prime}b_\lambda z_\lambda\in U$ and $\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_3^\prime}c_\lambda w_\lambda\in V$. Therefore,
$$x=u+v,$$
with $u\in U$ and $v\in V$.